# What is the dff parameter in transformer model?

Tags: transformer-model

In the paper, it describes the base model's network configuration are below:

[image]

```
d_model:  embedding size
h: attention head count
d_k: key matrix dimension
d_v: value matrix dimension
dff: 2048?
```

What's the dff?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.08668.pdf) paper, the dff is the **feed forward upwards projection size**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I didn't know this, I spent a lot of time learning Transformers but I don't know How I missed this, I don't know what is this, Is this present inside the decoder? Can you please explain what is this in simple language ?

Comment: @AravindR I'm no expert, but I believe it declares the **dimensionality of the output space**, just like in any other neural model. For example when using keras, `tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=dff, activation='relu')`, dff shows the number of output units, meaning the output arrays will be of shape (None, dff).

Comment: Sir, That was comes under dmodel parameter, the size of the dmodel is that 512, I will research about this.